# Slim Framework Routes Do Not Work When Application Receives Requests from a Subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

**Resume:** I need to do a request redirection using .htaccess, but my Slim Framework routes stop working when the redirection is executed.

---

I am developing a project for a company that has several institutional products. This company wants a custom website for each product, so each product will also have its own domain.

So for this case, I developed an application to manage the content of all websites from a single point.

I'll try to make it clear: When a user goes to product01.com, there will be a .htacces file at the root of this site that will send the request to an "app" folder. And it is in this folder "app" that my application will actually be located.

When a user accesses product02.com, the same should happen. And it's very important to make it clear that the URL that the user will access and that he will continue to see after access will be productX.com

Note that I will not have any code in the product folders. Everything will be located in the "app" folder.

I managed to make the requests work, but the problem started when I started using Slim Framework to manage my application routes.

When I access my "app" folder without going through any directions, everything works normally. But when I route requests from "product" to "app", Slim's routes stop working.

If I go from "productX" to a project that doesn't use Slim Framework to manage routes, everything works perfectly. So my difficulty is making this targeting work with Slim.

I have tried dozens of settings for the .htaccess files in all project folders and my result is the same: when I direct a request to the project that uses Slim Framework, the routes stop working. Error 404 is always returned.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
- localhost (or public_html)
  - app (my application where I manage everything and also use the Slim Framework)
      - src
      - libs
      - .htaccess
  - product01 (in this folder there is only one .htaccess file that directs requests to the "app" folder)
      - .htacess
  - product02 (another folder that has only one .htaccess file that directs requests to the "app" folder)
      - .htacess
```

The contents of the product folders .htaccess file are as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ ../app/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) ../app/$1 [L]
```

The code above is enough to get a part of what I need: direct requests from productX.com to my "app" folder without changing the URL.

The code of the .htaccess file from the folder "app" is exactly the same that comes as suggested in Slim Framework library installation:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

In my "app" folder, where the Slim Framework library is installed, I am managing routes as follows:

```
<?php
require_once ('libs/vendor/autoload.php');

use \Slim\Slim;

$app = new Slim();

$app->get("/", function(){
    echo "Works!";
});

$app->get("/anything", function(){
    echo "Works Too!";
});

$app->run();
```

The whole problem I'm facing is not knowing how to set up .htaccess files correctly or because I'm not knowing how to set up routes.

---

To make it easier for you to visualize my problem I have uploaded my application to my own domain.

**Visit the following links to see the application working normally (without any redirection):**

[Application working normally without .htaccess redirection: app](https://uaiser.com.br/app)

[Application working normally without .htaccess redirection: app/anything](https://uaiser.com.br/app/anything)

**In the following link you can see the redirection working normally, just because I'm not using Slim Framwork to manage routes:**

[This link works normally because the folder that receives the requests does not make use of the Slim Framework.](https://uaiser.com.br/product02/)

In fact, from the link above you can see "product02", but there is no content in the "product02" folder. The only thing inside is a .htaccess file that directs you to a folder called "normal".

Now, on the link below, you will see the problem I am facing. I am trying to enter the "product01" folder, which has no file other than an .htaccess file by directing requests to the "app" folder. Note that app folder routes work normally when they are accessed directly, as I showed in the first two links. These same routes stop working when I try to direct from the "product01" folder to the "app" folder:

[The routes that were working on the first two links stop working because I'm directing from "product01" to "app".](https://uaiser.com.br/product01)

---

I apologize for such a large text. But I really have no idea how to achieve what I want, and the only way I can get help is by explaining my problem in detail.

I also created a folder with the files of this project. You can download it by [clicking here](http://uaiser.com.br/project.zip). I am using Docker to create my development environment. So in this link are also the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml that I use.

I appreciate any help or insight to solving this problem. Thank you!!!

---

**P.S.¹:** I don't know if I'm using the tags correctly. I apologize if I am exaggerating including issues that do not relate to the problem described above. I appreciate any clarification related to this and any suggestion to change or improve the text I wrote.

**P.S.²:** I am Brazilian and I wrote part of this text with the help of translators. I apologize for the misuse of language and expressions. My intention is to make me understand and get your help =)

Comment: Why don't set VirtualMachines on apache sites-available, instead .htaccess. I think it's a better idea because the application handle domains and not only url paths. Maybe you want to put some code consuming the main app code, like App beeing the core and the subfolders codes beeing some kind of "view" of core already with custom data depending on subfolder. I suggest you GuzzleHTTP

Comment: Have you tried to set the correct basepath with `$app->setBasePath(...);` https://github.com/selective-php/basepath. Edit: For Slim 3 try this: https://odan.github.io/2017/11/30/creating-your-first-slim-framework-application.html#front-controller